# returning all result using spring-data-rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am following spring data rest from https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/ and  I am only using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I would like to know how can I return all records (`without pagination`) but not using spring-boot-starter-web.I wants to keep my code as small as possible.

I tried following but it is not working

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people" , path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository  extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findAllByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
    default List<Person> findAll(){
        Pageable pageable = null;
        return (List<Person>) this.findAll(pageable);
    };
}
```

I mean if I have whole MVC, I can do it but I like to keep my code to minimum.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You say you're trying to use "spring-boot-data-rest", but you want to use that without using the "web" starter? There is no "spring-boot-data-rest" dependency, only the "starter" (spring-boot-starter-data-rest), which itself includes Spring MVC. So no matter what, if you're using Spring Data REST, you're including Spring MVC as well.

Do you want a REST endpoint, but no paging? Or something else?

Comment: @TedM.Young I have corrected my question. I want a REST endpoint but no paging.

Answer (score 0):

> Spring Data REST is itself a Spring MVC application and is designed in
>   such a way that it should integrate with your existing Spring MVC
>   applications with little effort. An existing (or future) layer of
>   services can run alongside Spring Data REST with only minor additional
>   work.

---

If you are using current version of spring boot, there is no need to mark your repository with `@RepositoryRestResource`; also spring will auto-configure Spring Data Rest once it found the spring-data-rest dependency in your path, bellow you will find steps with minimum config :

In pom.xml :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Define your Entity + Repository :

**Order.java**

```
@Entity(name = "SampleOrder")
@Data
public class Order {

    @Id @GeneratedValue//
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

**OrderRepository.java**

```
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Long> {

}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Test your API :

```
curl http://localhost:8080
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/hal+json
{ "_links" : {
    "orders" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/orders"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this still did not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

As @abdelghani-roussi shows, you can use the `CrudRepository` instead of the `PagingAndSortingRepository`, e.g.:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {
  List<Person> findAllByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
  // don't need to define findAll(), it's defined by CrudRepository
}
```

and then the default `findAll()` method will return a `List<Person>` that isn't paged.

Note: as I mentioned in my comment, by including the dependency on `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` you are *also* pulling in the Web dependencies, so you can't avoid that.